# How does Gnome Files choose the user when mounting a drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, mount, gnome

I have a USB drive with two partitions on it:
one ext4 partition of 100GB and one ntfs partition of 20GB.

When I plug the drive in, Gnome Files automatically mount them on `/media/<user>`.
However, the ext4 partition is owned by user `1001` and group `1001` whereas the ntfs one is owned by `<user>`.

How can I configure it so that the ext4 partition is also owned by `<user>`? And why is it owned by `1001` even though `/etc/group` has no group with such id...

I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks!

Comment: Is 1001 not the uid for <user> ?

Answer (score 1):

When most external drives are mounted, `udisks2` looks at the type of the file system and applies certain mount options, including deciding whether to mount the drive for the user logged in on the currently active seat or not.

Because ext4 is a native file system for Linux, it's assumed that the user might want permissions to be preserved, since it's completely capable of supporting the full range of multi-user Unix permissions desired, including things like extended attributes.  However, a file system like NTFS or FAT is not native and not capable of those things, so it's assumed it's an external device and mounted for the current user.  Even UDF, which natively supports POSIX semantics but is commonly used on removable media, uses the current user for mounting by default.

`udisks2` should be able to be configured with `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf`.  On many systems, there is a sample file called `/etc/udisks2/mount_options.conf.example` which shows the example syntax and the defaults.  You can use the `uid=$UID,gid=$GID` mount options to make it mount for the currently logged in user.