# Mounting ext4 and making active user own the files

Tags: linux, mount, file-permissions

OK, so I could not come up with a meaningful title, but the problem is this: I have a removable drive that I created on laptop A. There my user was the first created, so all files on the removable drive are owned by user 1000.

When I mount the drive on laptop A, I can work with the files without any problem, e.g. I can read files with mode bits 400. However, on laptop B, my user is the *second* one (hence, 1001). So when I mount the drive there on GUI (KDE), I cannot access the same files, because I don't own them.

The question is: can I mount the drive in such a way that I end up owning the files? Preferably something automatic so that I don't have to go to the CLI every time I mount something. It seems as if [this could be achieved by udisks](https://superuser.com/questions/1566052/), but the answer there was sparse on details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an ID mapping feature was only added very recently (Linux kernel v5.12 or later); it still needs an update to the util-linux `mount` command before it becomes generally accessible, but you can try building the [mount-idmapped](https://github.com/brauner/mount-idmapped) tool instead:

```
# mount-idmapped --map-mount=u:1000:1001 /run/media/david/MyHDD /mnt/MyHDD_mapped
```

(Update: `mount` in latest util-linux now has this feature built in, although the option is different.)

If this feature is not available in the kernel you're running (or if you can't install "mount-idmapped"), you'll need to use the FUSE-based `bindfs` overlay:

```
# bindfs --map=1000/1001 /run/media/david/MyHDD /mnt/MyHDD_mapped
```

I would still recommend unifying your UID across all systems (`usermod` and careful `chown`).

> It seems as if this could be achieved by udisks

At the moment – no, as ext4 doesn't support the uid/gid options that vfat/ntfs drivers have. (Nobody seems to realize that `uid=` and `gid=` options are implemented individually by each filesystem...)

Comment: Thank you, `bindfs` worked like a charm. I mean, it's not GUI and you need root, but at least it does what I wanted. Thanks! BTW, am I right in assuming that you unmount the mapped directory with `fusermount -u`?

Comment: In other cases yes, but since you had to mount it as root, you can just use the regular `umount`.